# Can someone explain these poor SVM scores on a binary classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I am testing out different SVM kernels on a cats vs dogs image dataset. The problem is the training and test accuracy is really poor. I could never increase my accuracy on the test set over 0.47. The best I could do was increase the training accuracy to 0.97 by changing parameters on the rbf and the poly kernel. Maybe I messed up while I was preparing my data? The basic steps I did was read each picture, turn it grayscale and turn it into an appropriate array. Afterwards I just create a dataframe and normalise the pixel values of the images(the code is below). Another guess of mine is the dataset is just bad when it comes to the svm model? The pictures are very different and random? Can anyone help me figure out why the accuracy scores never go up? Why the model is showing such poor performance? (I have tried different values of C, gamma, degree parameters in their respective kernels without success).

```
catimages = []
dogimages = []
for img in glob.glob("/home/mr_robot/Downloads/cd/PetImages/Cat/*.jpg"):
    image = Image.open(img)
    rez = image.resize((28,28))
    gray = ImageOps.grayscale(rez)
    array = np.array(gray)
    catimages.append(array)
a = np.array(catimages, dtype=object)
z = a.reshape(12498, 784)
catdata = pd.DataFrame(z)
catdata.insert(loc=0, column="label", value=0)
for img in glob.glob("/home/mr_robot/Downloads/cd/PetImages/Dog/*.jpg"):
    image2 = Image.open(img)
    rez2 = image.resize((28,28))
    gray2 = ImageOps.grayscale(rez2)
    array2 = np.array(gray2)
    dogimages.append(array2)
a2 = np.array(dogimages, dtype=object)
z2 = a.reshape(12498, 784)
dogdata = pd.DataFrame(z2)
dogdata.insert(loc=0, column="label", value=1)
data = pd.concat([catdata,dogdata])
data = data.sample(frac=1)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi there  Questions like this tend not to do well (there was a really similar [question a couple days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74827639/svm-image-classifier-prediction-low-accuracy)). But this question could be improved by editing to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Quick debugging step: make sure to apply *all* data preprocessing steps to both the training and test set. 50% accuracy on balanced classes is random guessing: and usually this happens if the train/test distributions are wildly different.

Comment: I basically split the above data with train test split so the preprocessing is the same on both train and test images. Looking at the pictures they are really different from each other (different breeds, angles, objects closer or further away or even being held by people). Maybe that's all the SVM can do in this specific dataset and I'm overthinking it? It worked really well in data like MNIST.